# Scanner recognition

Tags: printing, hp

I have a HP Photosmart B210 connected via USB to the computer, which prints fine. However when attempting to scan from the device, I get the error message "Make sure the printer installed properly, and then start the scan job with computer" on the device's display screen (not on the computer). I tried reinstalling the device driver from HP with no avail. 
I cannot find a method to start the scan from the computer. When this device was installed when running windows, it scanned fine from the device. I'm running 14.04 LTS. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: What happens if you start `simple-scan`? Does it find your scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Scanner drivers and Utility package :

```
sudo apt-get install sane xsane xsane-common sane-utils libsane libsane-common libsane-dbg libsane-dev libsane-extras libsane-extras-common libsane-extras-dbg libsane-extras-dev simple-scan
```

Then try to manage the scanner with the application, Simple Scan

Comment: Perfect! Got Simple Scan to recognize the scanner. THanks for the help!